# Android Activity switch loses fullscreen temporarily

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, splash-screen

Can someone help me out here. I have a Splash screen as an Activity in my fullscreen App (landscape). When the Splash screen calls the main activity (with no animation) i lose fullscreen momentarily and see the titlebar before the next activity pops up, how can I prevent this? It looks ugly and un-professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare the fullscreen theme for the complete app.

Comment: Just to elaborate, one should set the Fullscreen flag in all activities that require fullscreen. getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);, there is also a this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); which is different, it hides the title only and not the status bar too, but can be set in the manifest on activities where no title is wanted.